# hadoop os x mrjob $HADOOP_HOME not set

Tags: java, python, macos, hadoop, mapreduce

I have set up hadoop on my os x local machine using the following tutorial - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brandonwerner/archive/2011/11/13/how-to-set-up-hadoop-on-os-x-lion-10-7.aspx

I ran the word count example and everything worked fine. Now, I want to write map reduce jobs using python and run it on my local hadoop implementation. I am trying the open source 'mrjob' framework. I was able to run their word count example  job locally, but when i try it on the hadoop implementation like this -

```
$python mrjob/examples/mr_word_freq_count.py README.rst -r hadoop > counts
```

I get an error saying $HADOOP_HOME not set, it must passed explicitly.
I edited the .bash_profile file and when i echo $HADOOP_HOME from the terminal i get '/usr/local/hadoop'

I couldn't find good documentation for the mrjob framework on hadoop. I just need to get started, so that i can run the example word count job in mrjob.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the maintainers. You should open a ticket on Github the next time you have an issue like this. We don't watch Stack Overflow at all.

The Hadoop runner gets less love than the rest of the framework, but we're fixing an issue that sounds related in the next release, v0.3.5: https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob/issues/482

Please send further bug reports to Github.